# How to make a PIVOT query with two values (columns)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to create a two columns PIVOT query. The structure is like the following:

```
DECLARE @Tmp TABLE(  Id1 int, Id2 int,  Name nvarchar(20), Val1 int, Val2 nvarchar(10))
```

With the following dummy data:

```
        INSERT INTO @Tmp VALUES(1,10,'A',2,'str1'), (1,11,'B',2,'str2'),     
(2,10,'A',3,'str3'),(3,11,'B',4, null),(4,11,'B',5,'str4'),(4,10,'A',5,null)
```

What I'm trying to achive is a PIVOT query with 2 different values(`Val1, Val2`). I did try the following query, however, It is not possible to group the values in the result because `Val2` is a `nvarchar`

```
     SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT Id1, Name, Val1, Val2, Name +'_Val2' AS ColVal2  FROM @Tmp) AS tb 
        PIVOT(MIN(Val1) FOR Name IN([A],[B])) pv
        PIVOT(MIN(Val2) FOR ColVal2 IN([A_Val2],[B_Val2])) pv2
        -- GROUP BY could go here ...
```

Something important to say is  the query will be dynamic because the values in `Name` are not fixed, ie `Id1` can be related to n `Id2`

The desired output should look like this:

```
Id1     A   B     A_Val2    B_Val2  
 1      2   2       str1    str2  
 2      3   NULL    str3    NULL 
 3   NULL   4       NULL    NULL  
 4      5   5       NULL    str4
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to achieve using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT Id1,
       [A] = Min(CASE WHEN NAME = 'a' THEN Val1 END),
       [B] = Min(CASE WHEN NAME = 'b' THEN Val1 END),
       [A_Val2] = Min(CASE WHEN NAME = 'a' THEN Val2 END),
       [B_Val2] = Min(CASE WHEN NAME = 'b' THEN Val2 END)
FROM   @Tmp
GROUP  BY Id1
```

Here is a dynamic version(change the table variable to temp table)

```
declare @col_list varchar(max) = '',@sql varchar(max)

set @col_list = stuff((select distinct ','+quotename(Name),',' ,quotename(Name+'_Val2') from #Tmp for xml path('')),1,1,'')
--select @col_list
set @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Id1,
               col,
               val
        FROM   #Tmp
               CROSS apply (VALUES (Cast(Val1 AS VARCHAR(50)),NAME),
                                   (Val2,NAME + ''_Val2'')) cs (val, col))a
       PIVOT (Max(val)
             FOR col IN ('+@col_list+')) pv' 

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: The values in Name are not fixed, ie, there can be several Names. Id2 represents a table relation

Comment: @Shnugo - I love pivot question ;)

Comment: Man, the way you reordered the data using CROSS APPLY and Values is **AWESOME**. There is nothing left to say. Just Thank you. I even think  the solution has good performance. I have to check that more carefully

Comment: This is so beautiful

Comment: @Ayorus If you care about performance then we can convert the conditonal aggregate into dynamic query. Just for fun I wrote pivot answer

Comment: The query will never return more than 800 rows. I think it is Ok. If it is not enough I will try to implement the conditional aggregate as you suggested. Thanks =D!!